# effective way to determine if a message is spam?

Tags: nlp, spam-prevention

Is there a way to determine if the given message is a spam? For example those who posts on forums and advertise their own sites for various products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways, non of which are fool proof.

The current technology that achieves the best results is [bayesian inference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_inference) for statistical analysis.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to look at where it came from.  Most spam comes from certain ISPs and there are lists of those available.

Another way is to check where the posts links lead.  IE if the links in the post lead to a completely unrelated site or a known spammer haven, it's probably spam.